# A list of places that you would go to for something you need

Tags: single-word-requests

Like,

- grocery store
- utilities store
- meat shop
- car wash
- bank

These are the places (unordered) I would normally go to regularly and possibly all of them in a single day. Is there a name for this kind of list? Or something descriptive along something common in each of those...

Comment: Are you looking for something more specific than *to-do list* or *errands*?

Comment: Chores? Errands? Do the rounds?

Comment: My English grannies used to talk about "going to the shops." In Canada, I talk about "going into town" (I live outside of a small town) -- this term implies that I'm going to do some or all of those things.

Comment: "Retail and Service Establishments" might work for a heading.

Comment: I've never heard anyone talk of a 'meat shop' - the term 'butchers' is the usual one (with or without an apostrophe). And come to think of it, what is a 'utilities store?' We tend to reserve the term 'utility' for gas and electricity suppliers in UK English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides *errand list* for referring to the list itself, consider  *[itinerary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/itinerary#Noun)*, “A route or proposed route of a journey”, which would apply if you've written the items in travel order.   Some terms for referring to the set of places, moreso than the list itself, include *[reach](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reach#Noun)*, *[range](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/range#Noun)*, *[ambit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambit#Noun)*, *[gamut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gamut#Noun)*, *[scope](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scope#Noun)*,  *[purview](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/purview#Noun)*, and *[circuit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circuit#Noun)* (like “A regular or appointed journeying from place to place in the exercise of one's calling, as of a judge, or a preacher”).

Answer (score 1):

If those are all errands, then it's an "errand list."